# Fudge Recipes - Shelf Life

Tags: storage-lifetime, fudge

I am looking for information on how to extend the shelf life of the fudge that I make for my business. Currently it is only lasting about 2 weeks, even when we have it sealed, we take it out and when we take it out it only lasts a couple days. I currently use a variety of methods as we are trying to find the best one.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Recipe requests are off topic. In order for us to be able to help, you will need to edit your question to include recipes and/or methods that you are using. Otherwise, we have no way of suggesting what you may be able to do differently to improve your results as we don't know what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Fudge really only has a shelf life of a week or two. First it will start to crystallize on the outside (which is actually very yummy in my opinion), but then it will start to grow mold. Good hygiene will lengthen the time before mold starts to grow, but ultimately fudge is not a preserved food and isn't meant to keep. The individual ingredients will keep better by themselves, and you can make the fudge nearly on demand.